# Get a 28-byte number from uint64 in C

Tags: c

I would like to get a 28-byte number from multiple 64-bit inputs.

I want to use the True Random Number Generator of AM3352. It generates an output of 64 bits. And I want to create a 28-byte number that would be randomly generated by the TRNG of the AM3352 and use the "salt" for a password like : Hashed password = password + salt

For example, I get : `val1 = 2411177729172638042`, `val 2 = 11787499938100258610`, etc. I need 4 such values to get 28 bytes. I would like to have a 28-byte number from these `uint64` values.

How to do it?

Comment: 64 bits = 8 bytes. 2 x 8 bytes = 16 bytes. 16 bytes is significantly less than 24 bytes.

Comment: Yep I corrected it, so imagine I have 4 values of 8 bytes, that's 32 bytes and I only 28 bytes from these 4 values, what is the easiest way to do it ? For now I thought about converting the output in a 8 bytes result
uint8_t *p = (uint8_t *)&value;
uint8_t result[8]; 
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { 
   result[i] = p[i];}

Comment: what is a *salt* of 28 bytes?  providing examples of expected input and output could clarify your question

Comment: I want to use the True Random Number Generator of AM3352. It generates an output of 64 bits. And I want to create a 28 bytes number that would be randomly generated by the TRNG of the AM3352 and use the "salt" for a password like : Hashed password = password + salt

Comment: @picklerick is it clear for you ?

Comment: @PierreP Okay, it's clear what you're trying to do now. It would be good if you could update your question with the information you added in your comments. When doing that, do try to ensure any code is properly formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for something like this?

```
extern uint64_t rng(void); // produced an b6-bit random number

void make_salt(uint64_t i1, uint64_t i2, uint64_t i3, uint64_t i4, uint8_t * salt)   
{
  memcpy(salt, &i1, 8);
  memcpy(salt + 8, &i2, 8);
  memcpy(salt + 16, &i3, 8);
  memcpy(salt + 24, &i4, 4);
}

uint8_t salt[28];
make_salt(rng(), rng(), rng(), rng(), salt);
```